# How to replace strip lights with LED down lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring, led, uk

I have an old, broken, mains-powered, strip light fixture mounted under a cabinet like this:

[image: The cable comes from the mains]

Is it possible to buy an LED light fitting that I can wire straight in, if I just remove the old fixture? Is there something extra I need to have, like some sort of voltage adapter, or do they usually come as standard with units like [this](https://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/revive-square-under-cabinet-light?categoryId=8a0b4ead-044b-40f5-bd33-b431e8c38710-9DACF:en-GB)?

Comment: Is that cord plugged into a socket, or cable coming out of the wall?

Comment: You link to a UK retailer. If you're also in the UK, it's most likely that the item you've linked to will be designed to run on the UK power system and won't need any adaptation at all.

Comment: @Huesmann cable coming out of the wall.

Comment: @FreeMan yes, UK power system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fitting you link to is a 24V fixture, so you will need a separate voltage converter.  It doesn't say whether it's 24V AC or DC and I can't find any installation instructions, so personally I would not choose this one.

Better would be to find a fixture that takes a 230V AC input, of which there are many.  Then you can simply wire the fixture into the existing wire that comes out of the wall if you wish.  Although the cable looks quite grotty so if possible I'd be tempted to replace that as well, if it is possible to access the other end of it.

If there is a place to mount a lighting transformer inside your cabinet then low voltage lights are also an option - probably only makes sense if you have a number of such lights or are using them in a wet area (like a bathroom or above the kitchen sink).

It is also possible to fit an LED tube to the existing strip light, but you would likely need to link out the starter inside it.  Since the existing light doesn't look in the best of condition I would personally be looking to replace it instead.

Answer (score 2):

All LED lamps will have a power supply to convert the 230V AC to something the LED module can use - often 12V DC.

Some lamps have the power supply built in.  Some require a separate power supply.  Shop around for whatever suits you.

Comment: Some LED lamps are long strings of LEDs which add up to ~80-120V, and then a capacitive dropper.  There is no power supply module inside, just resistor, capacitor and the LEDs.